# SVG onmouseover in CSS

Tags: css, svg

I have a question using CSS to create a changing onmouseover button. For a long time now I use the following code that calls for

```
<a href="../../../">
<img src="file-url" 
onmouseover="this.src='file-url'"
onmouseout="this.src='file-url'"
border="0" alt=""/></a>
</div>
```

Is it possible to instead of using an url use a svg string?

Thank you in advance for taking the time!!

Mitch

Comment: There are a few ways to use svg this article with it's links is the bees knees, I was just studying it the last couple of days https://24ways.org/2014/an-overview-of-svg-sprite-creation-techniques/

Answer (score 0):

Use your .svg as background image.

```
<a class="link" href="../../../"></a>

a.link {
    display: block;
    width: width of your svg;
    height: height of your svg;
    background: url(path/to/your/svg);
}

a.link:hover {
    background: url(path/to/your/hover/svg);
}
```

Comment: can you change the svg color on hover when it's a background @yonderboy?

Comment: no i don't think so. the background image is not part of the DOM so you can't manipulate it. i thought of producing two different svg's and change them on hover.